# Array - Order by value then priority if matching values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

The aim with my code is to find the 3 lowest values, however, if two of them are matching it needs to prioritise which one appears in the bottom 3.

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 50.00
    [5] => 59.38
    [4] => 62.50
    [2] => 62.50
    [7] => 66.67
    [8] => 68.75
    [6] => 80.00
    [9] => 91.67
)
```

The priority is the Key and the score is the Value.

Based on this example; Key 2 should be above key 4 as they both share the same value but the priority is greater on Key 2.

I hope this makes sense as I am starting to doubt my sanity with this, haha.

Many thanks,
Scott.

Comment: What you have tried please show code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little reformatting, then sorting:

```
$helpArr = array();
foreach ($yourArray as $prio => $score) {
  $helpArr[] = array($score, $prio);
}

sort($helpArray);
```

To get it back to your format:

```
$yourArray = array();
foreach ($helpArr as $h) {
  $yourArray[$h[0]] = $h[1];
}
```

Comment: let's make op's some try then answer would be better?

Comment: You can optimize this by flipping pairs: `($score, $prio)` and then just `sort` instead of `usort`.

Comment: @thg435 Thx, did not hear that before, but works. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort and arsort  function to fulfil your requirement .Check the below code may be it will help you.

```
<?php
 $arr = array(1=>50.00,5=>59.38,4=>62.50,2=>62.50,7=>66.67,8=>68.75,6=>80.00,9=>91.67);
 ksort($arr);
 arsort($arr);
 print_r($arr);
?>
```

Out Put :

```
   Array ( [9] => 91.67 [6] => 80 [8] => 68.75 [7] => 66.67 [4] => 62.5 [2] => 62.5 [5] => 59.38 [1] => 50 )
```

Now You will have list 3 value in bottom of your array.

Comment: Yes you are correct , I have modified the answer , may be it will done the trick .